# Marklogic Mapping, Matching and Merging documents for the last 24 hours

Tags: marklogic

In the marklogic datahub, currently all the mapping, mapping and merging is happening for the entire documents present in the datahub-STAGING and this takes more than 18 hours. I wanted to know if its possible to map, match and merge documents for the last 24 hours only.

Can I use a filter query in these 3 steps? If so, how?

Thank you!